# R markdown flextable formatting rows for word document

Tags: r, markdown, flextable

I am using R markdown and flextable to create a Word document, which would like contain a table like below but with some additional formatting. In general, I would like to format the negative numbers in red, which has been completed by using color() function. However, I cannot find the way to format the last two rows into percentage with %. I tried formattable package but not successful. Can someone provide some suggestions? Really appreciate!

Data:

```
structure(list(X25th.percentile = c(3.01462950348061, -0.349849435071161, 
0.25), X50th.percentile = c(4.1590809972998, -0.103031116474755, 
0.5), X75th.percentile = c(5.71021088599362, 0.231493564666972, 
0.75)), class = c("formattable", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), formattable = list(formatter = "format_table", format = list(
    list(area(col = 1:3) ~ function(x) percent(x, digits = 0))), 
    preproc = NULL, postproc = NULL))

  flextable(tbl)%>%
colformat_double(i=1,digit=2 )%>%
color(i=~ X25th.percentile<0, j="X25th.percentile", color="red")%>%
color(i=~X50th.percentile<0, j="X50th.percentile", color="red")%>%
color(i=~X75th.percentile<0, j="X75th.percentile", color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Please share some code and data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: @Quinten: Thanks. structure(list(X25th.percentile = c(3.01462950348061, -0.349849435071161, 
0.25), X50th.percentile = c(4.1590809972998, -0.103031116474755, 
0.5), X75th.percentile = c(5.71021088599362, 0.231493564666972, 
0.75)), class = c("formattable", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), formattable = list(formatter = "format_table", format = list(
    list(area(col = 1:3) ~ function(x) percent(x, digits = 0))), 
    preproc = NULL, postproc = NULL))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slightly refactor your code and use `ifelse`:

```
  tbl %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. < 1, paste0(. * 100, "%"), .))) %>% 
    flextable() %>% 
    colformat_double(i=1,digit=2 )%>%
    color(i=~ X25th.percentile<0, j="X25th.percentile", color="red")%>%
    color(i=~X50th.percentile<0, j="X50th.percentile", color="red")%>%
    color(i=~X75th.percentile<0, j="X75th.percentile", color="red")
```

This gives:

[image]

Not sure what your use-case is, but you also might want to consider rounding:

```
  tbl %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~round(., 2))) %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(. < 1, paste0(. * 100, "%"), .))) %>% 
    flextable() %>% 
    colformat_double(i=1,digit=2 )%>%
    color(i=~ X25th.percentile<0, j="X25th.percentile", color="red")%>%
    color(i=~X50th.percentile<0, j="X50th.percentile", color="red")%>%
    color(i=~X75th.percentile<0, j="X75th.percentile", color="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Matt answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063901/26964), you can also use the suffix argument of `colformat_double` to add the % sign:

```r
tbl |>
  mutate(across(.fns = \(x) replace(x, 2:3, 100*x[2:3]))) |>
  flextable() |>
  colformat_double(i=1,digits=2 ) |>
  color(i=~ X25th.percentile<0, j="X25th.percentile", 
        color="red") |>
  color(i=~X50th.percentile<0, j="X50th.percentile", 
        color="red") |>
  color(i=~X75th.percentile<0, j="X75th.percentile", 
        color="red") |>
  colformat_double(i=2:3, suffix='%', digits = 4)
```

[image]